# Onclick event doesn't work after AJAX in JQuery issue

Tags: jquery, ajax

This is the Jquery code:

```
$("#save").on ('click', function(){  // save new person
    var new_name = $("#name").val();
    var new_age = $("#age").val();

    var formData = { name : new_name, age : new_age }; 

    $.ajax({
        url : "ajax.php",
        type: "POST",
        data : formData,
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
            get_old_html = $("#result_json").html(); // getting current html data
            var array = JSON.parse(data);  // getting the JSON
            var html = "";
            for (var i = 0 ; i < array.length; i++){
                var split = array[i].split("||");
                html = html + "<tr><td>"+ split[1] +"</td><td>"+ split[2]  +"</td><td><center><a href ='#' class ='delete_person' id ='"+ split[0] +"'>X</a></center></td></tr>"; // create the new html with the new item
            }
            $("#result_json").html(html + get_old_html); // add the new html and the content of it

            $("#add_new_person").hide();
            $("#add_person").show(); 
                //mesaj de confirmare
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }
    });
});

$(".delete_person").on('click',function(){  //delete person
    id = $(this).attr("id");
    var formData = { id : id };
    $.ajax({
        url : "ajax.php",
        type: "POST",
        data : formData,
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
            var remove = JSON.parse(data);  // getting the JSON
            if (remove == "success"){
                $("#"+id).closest("tr").remove();
            }
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }
    });
});
```

The fact is then when i save a new person and after that I want to delete that person, the onclick event on the class "delete_person" does not work. But when I refreshed the page it works. What should I do ? and all of it is included in `$( document ).ready(function() { });`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`.delete-person` is an element that is dynamically added to the DOM *after* the AJAX call has been made. Since your jQuery script runs upon DOMready (when `.delete-person` is not present during runtime), the click event would not be bound to the element.

The line `$('.delete-person').on('click', function() { ... });` is functionally identical to `$('.delete-person').click(function() { ... });`. The gist is that you are attaching the click event handler to the element `.delete-person`, which is not present in the DOM at runtime.

Instead, listen to the click event originating from `.delete-person` that is bubbling up to the `document` object instead:

```
$(document).on('click', '.delete-person', function() {
    // Do stuff here to delete person
});
```

What the above code does differently is that you are listening for the click even on the `document` object, but verifying that the click event originated from a child element that has a class of `.delete-person`. Since the click event will always bubble to the `document` regardless of whether the object is present or absent during runtime, you will be able to delete the person this way ;)

Comment: doesn't `.on()` mentioned in the question work the same way as yours?

Comment: Thank you so much Terry, very well explained.

Answer (score 0):

make sure about response data
and use

```
$(this).closest("tr").remove();
```

or try:

```
$(".delete_person").on('click',function(){ 
    var element = $(this);
```

then

```
$(element).closest("tr").remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you should just add a native javascript function
like this

```
for (var i = 0 ; i < array.length; i++){
                var split = array[i].split("||");
                html = html + "<td><a href='#' onlick='deletePerson("+split[1]+")'>Delete</a></td>" // create the new html with the new item
            }
```

then outsude your $(document)

```
function deletePerson(id){
    var person_id = id  ;
    //ajax code here
 }
```

this is what I do whenever i have a dynamic table that has a remove function using jquery

Answer (score 0):

It is because the element doesn't exist in the document. You need to use

```
$(document).on("click", "selector", function(){do something});
```

Hope this helps :)

Happy Learning :)